# Android - How to converting inputted random words to numbers

Tags: java, android

How to convert a word in a string to a numbers?

e.g. **STACK** would output as 1-2-3-4-5.

so **S=1**, **T=2**, **A=3**, **C=4**, **K=5**.

Comment: I would suggest looking at how to get the length of the string/text you input as a start and see if you can figure out a way from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a solution:

```
/**
     * Convert a given string to array of numbers.
     * 
     * @param words
     *            The string
     * @param startValue
     *            The start value for the array.
     * @return The array of numbers.
     */
    public static final int[] wordsToNumbers(String words, int startValue) {
        if (words == null || words.length() == 0) {
            return new int[0];
        } else {
            int[] numbers = new int[words.length()];
            int value = startValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
                numbers[i] = value;
                value++;
            }
            return numbers;
        }
    }
```

**Let's test this:**

```
String test = "STACK";
int[] numbers = wordsToNumbers(test, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
    char c = test.charAt(i);
    System.out.printf("%s=%d\n", c, numbers[i]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
S=1
T=2
A=3
C=4
K=5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how to use that value in a strings? e.g: String number = String.valueOf(HashMap);

Comment: @Bonnie7 see my updated answer.

Comment: So, we can just use one value (e.g: S or K), is'n it? How to use all values of that (STACK = 12345)?

Comment: Using a hash map has a limitation so I update new code to work with any given string.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to hear that.